# How to get dmgr host and port number dynamically using jython and jacl in IBM Websphere Application Server in linux?

Tags: websphere, jython

I need to get Dmgr host and port dynamically to sync the node.

`AdminControl.getHost() and AdminControl.getPort()`

I am not sure whether i works. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work instead at the end of your administrative script?

```
AdminConfig.save()
if (NDInstall == "ND"):
    nodeSync = AdminControl.completeObjectName("type=NodeSync,node=" + nodeLongName + ",*")
    AdminControl.invoke(nodeSync, "sync")
```

Comment: No i didn't use above code in my script.. i know that before sync node should stop the node and stop server in that node..Is there must to stop all java process in profile bin directory before stopping the node?

Answer (score 0):

A save and sync by itself doesn't require nodes or application servers to be down.  Depending on the nature of the change you may need to recycle application servers to bring the change into effect.  One feature that's in ND to help with high availability is the ability to ripple start servers in a cluster.  This way one or more application servers stay up to service requests while a change is 'rippled' into effect.

A cluster is also an administrative unit that can be stopped and started.  You can arrange your clusters however you want across your nodes.